# How can I make the words in x axis appear from right to left in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]
I have a list of tuples. In every tuple there is a word (in Persian) and a number that shows its frequency. When I run the code to plot, words in horizontal axis appear to be aligned from left to right which is the wrong order! I did some searching and found that I need to use "arabic_reshaper". I could successfully reshape and align the words in labels, however, I couldn't find a way to do the same for x axis.

The third word in the list (('کلمات', 1046)) is the same as the label for x axis only inverted! Is there any quick fix for that?

```
from bidi.algorithm import get_display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import arabic_reshaper

data = [('اندر', 1609), ('جان', 1296), ('کلمات', 1046), ('دل', 896)]


x = [x[0] for x in data]
y = [x[1] for x in data]


xlbl = get_display( arabic_reshaper.reshape('کلمات'))
ylbl = get_display( arabic_reshaper.reshape('فراوانی'))
plt.bar(x, y, label='Bar1', color='blue')
plt.xlabel(xlbl, fontdict=None, labelpad=None)
plt.ylabel(ylbl, fontdict=None, labelpad=None)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I only mean the order of words (letters) not the whole order.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of searching, I finally got the answer!

here is the new code:

```
from bidi.algorithm import get_display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import arabic_reshaper
from arabic_reshaper import reshape

data = [('اندر', 1609), ('جان', 1296), ('کلمات', 1046), ('دل', 896)]


x = [get_display(reshape(x[0])) for x in data] #pesky fix!
y = [x[1] for x in data]


print(x)
xlbl = get_display( arabic_reshaper.reshape('کلمات'))
ylbl = get_display( arabic_reshaper.reshape('فراوانی'))
plt.bar(x, y, label='Bar1', color='blue')
plt.xlabel(xlbl, fontdict=None, labelpad=None)
plt.ylabel(ylbl, fontdict=None, labelpad=None)
plt.savefig('pie.png', dpi=200)
plt.show()
```

[image]